# indexing a max + group by query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

How do create an index for this query? I've tried every possible combination of indexes I can think of but explain plan always shows a SEQ_SCAN is being used.

```
select exchange_id, currency, max(timestamp) timestamp2
    from exchange_balance
    where account_id = 'foo'
    group by exchange_id, currency
```

The table isn't large right now and so it's actually quite fast, but it will grow quickly.

PostgreSQL 9.6

[edit] added a group by col - sorry

I've tried this for example:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_exchange_balance_1 ON exchange_balance (exchange_id, currency, timestamp desc, account_id);
```

But always a table scan on a table with 45k rows

Comment: "The table isn't large right now ..." -- and maybe that's the reason not using any index seems faster to the optimizer. But I think `(account_id, exchange_id, timestamp DESC)` could be a promising candidate.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that (and many other combinations) not no luck - always results in a full scan. ( BTW "not large" means around 27k rows right now... actually don't know if that's considered large or not)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the statistics are stale and an [`ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) brings a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select exchange_id, currency, max(timestamp) as timestamp2
from exchange_balance
where account_id = 'foo'
group by exchange_id, currency;
```

The best index is `(account_id, exchange_id, currency, timestamp desc)`.

In Postgres, this might be more efficient using:

```
select distinct on (account_id, exchange_id, currency) exchange_id, currency, timestamp
from exchange_balance
where account_id = 'foo'
order by account_id, exchange_id, currency, timestamp desc;
```

Strictly speaking, `account_id` is not needed in  the `order by` or `distinct on` clause.  But keeping them allows the query to generalize to multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that (`create index test_idx on exchange_balance (account_id, exchange_id, currency, timestamp desc)`) and my query still results in a full table scan.  For the original query at least.  It does get used for your suggested alternate query.  Are they equivalent (sorry, my sql isn't that great)?

Comment: @pomo . . . The two queries are basically equivalent, in that they generate the same result set.  If `timestamp` can be `NULL`, you actually want `timestamp desc nulls last` for the `order by`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out then.  That column is NOT NULL