# PostgreSQL multi-column group by not using index when selecting minimum

Tags: postgresql, indexing, group-by, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

When selecting `MIN` on a column in PostgreSQL (11, 12, 13) after a `GROUP BY` operation on multiple columns, any index created on the grouped columns is not used: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=30e0f341940f4c1fa6013677643a0baf

```
CREATE TABLE tags (id serial, series int, index int, page int);
CREATE INDEX ON tags (page, series, index);

INSERT INTO tags (series, index, page)
SELECT
    ceil(random() * 10),
    ceil(random() * 100),
    ceil(random() * 1000)
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT tags.page, tags.series, MIN(tags.index)
FROM tags GROUP BY tags.page, tags.series;
```

```
HashAggregate  (cost=2291.00..2391.00 rows=10000 width=12) (actual time=108.968..133.153 rows=9999 loops=1)
  Group Key: page, series
  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1425kB
  ->  Seq Scan on tags  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=12) (actual time=0.015..55.240 rows=100000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.257 ms
Execution Time: 133.771 ms
```

Theoretically, the index should allow the database to seek in steps of `(tags.page, tags.series)` instead of performing a full scan. This would result in 10,000 processed rows for above dataset instead of 100,000. [This link](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/speeding-up-min-and-max/) describes the method with no grouped columns.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/5114106) (as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305982/indexing-a-max-group-by-query)) suggests using `DISTINCT ON` with an ordering instead of `GROUP BY` but that produces this query plan:

```
Unique  (cost=0.42..5680.42 rows=10000 width=12) (actual time=0.066..268.038 rows=9999 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using tags_page_series_index_idx on tags  (cost=0.42..5180.42 rows=100000 width=12) (actual time=0.064..227.219 rows=100000 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 100000
Planning Time: 0.426 ms
Execution Time: 268.712 ms
```

While the index is now being used, it still appears to be scanning the full set of rows. When using `SET enable_seqscan=OFF`, the `GROUP BY` query degrades to the same behaviour.

How can I encourage PostgreSQL to use the multi-column index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can pull the set of distinct page,series from another table then you can hack it with a lateral join:

```
CREATE TABLE pageseries AS SELECT DISTINCT page,series FROM tags ORDER BY page,series;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT p.*, minindex FROM pageseries p CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT index minindex FROM tags t WHERE t.page=p.page AND t.series=p.series ORDER BY page,series,index LIMIT 1) x;
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..8720.00 rows=10000 width=12) (actual time=0.039..56.013 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on pageseries p  (cost=0.00..145.00 rows=10000 width=8) (actual time=0.012..1.872 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.84 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=10000)
         ->  Index Only Scan using tags_page_series_index_idx on tags t  (cost=0.42..4.62 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=10000)
               Index Cond: ((page = p.page) AND (series = p.series))
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.168 ms
 Execution Time: 57.077 ms
```

...but it is not necessarily faster:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE                                                                                                                                              SELECT tags.page, tags.series, MIN(tags.index)
FROM tags GROUP BY tags.page, tags.series;

 HashAggregate  (cost=2291.00..2391.00 rows=10000 width=12) (actual time=56.177..58.923 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Group Key: page, series
   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1425kB
   ->  Seq Scan on tags  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=12) (actual time=0.010..12.845 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.129 ms
 Execution Time: 59.644 ms
```

It would be massively faster IF the number of iterations in the nested loop was small, in other words if there was a low number of distinct (page,series). I'll try with series alone, since that has only 10 distinct values:

```
CREATE TABLE series AS SELECT DISTINCT series FROM tags;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT p.*, minindex FROM series p CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT index minindex FROM tags t WHERE t.series=p.series ORDER BY series,index LIMIT 1) x;
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..886.18 rows=2550 width=8) (actual time=0.081..0.264 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on series p  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=10)
         ->  Index Only Scan using tags_series_index_idx on tags t  (cost=0.29..211.29 rows=10000 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=10)
               Index Cond: (series = p.series)
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.198 ms
 Execution Time: 0.292 ms
```

In this case, definitely worth it, because the query hits only 10/100000 rows. The other queries hit 10000/100000 rows, or 10% of the table, which is above the threshold where an index would really help.

Note putting the column with lower cardinality first will result in a smaller index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tags (series, page, index);
select pg_relation_size( 'tags_page_series_index_idx' );
          4284416
select pg_relation_size( 'tags_series_page_index_idx' );
          3104768
```

...but it doesn't make the query any faster.

If this type of stuff is really critical, perhaps try clickhouse or dolphindb.

Answer (score 1):

To support that kind of thing PostgreSQL would have to have something like an *index skip scan*, and it is only efficient to use that if there are few groups.

If the speed of that query is essential, you could consider using a materialized view.